# Liquibase - Test changeset before executing

Tags: liquibase

I have a pipeline Jenkins that execute liquibase scripts. However, lots of time the pipeline failed because there are errors in the script.

I would like to test my script locally before running the pipeline. I would run the script locally to detect if there are errors (syntaxe problem, column that doesn't exist, etc), without creating an entry in the databasechangelog.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run [updateSQL](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/updatesql.html), which will display the sql that liquibase update WOULD run.  You can take that sql and run it in any SQL query IDE of your choice to test syntax.